# Angular Universal (SSR) cache don't update

Tags: angular, apache, caching, pm2, universal

Good,
I have a web with Angular Universal on an Apache server executed through PM2.

When making changes, I generate the new version of the web, upload the files to the hosting and restart the pm2 task

But when accessing the web the changes are not shown. For them to be displayed I have to clear data from the site or force the cache to be cleared.

For example, in a browser that I haven't used for 2 months, I still get the look it had then, even if I refresh the page.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.